# How do we calculate total probability of data by taking account all of our hypothesis in Bayesian Inference?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

Given a Bayesian Inference Formula

$P(H\mid E)={\frac {P(E\mid H)\cdot P(H)}{P(E)}}$.

How can we ever calculate the total probability of all of our models? This seems impossible given a large number of models. So along with the requirement of prior probability, shouldn't this also be considered as 
 a critical factor of success in Bayesian inference as well when we are setting up our experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Statistical tool has its own limitations and we have to know them before we could start our analysis. Bayesian allow us to compute the probability of our hypothesis given data yet we need to know the prior probability and the total probability given our models are true and also the likelihood that we know our models beforehand which in most of the scientific studies we don't. So people guess prior probabilities and their likely models before they start their scientific studies which could lead to wrong results.